# error C2436 member function or nested class in constructor initializer list

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a function pointer declared in my header, like this:

```
typedef void (intCB)(int );
```

and I have a class member declared like this:

```
private:
  intCB m_intCB;
```

In my constructor's initialization list I want to initialize it with 0:

```
MyClass::MyClass : m_intCB(0)
{
   #ifdef SOMETHING
   m_intCB = &someOtherFunc;
   #endif
}
```

Only if a specific define is in place, I want to set m_intCB to it, if not I want to keep it on 0. The problem with the above code is that I receive:

```
error C2436: 'm_intCB' : member function or nested class in constructor initializer list
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not a function pointer, you are missing a `*`. Try:

```
typedef void (*intCB)(int);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `typedef` is wrong, it should be `typedef void (*intCB)(int );`

Answer (score 2):

Function pointer is a **pointer**, so don't miss *

```
typedef void (*intCB)(int);
```

Comment: It's `(*intCB)` not `(intCB*)`

Answer (score 1):

And:

```
MyClass::MyClass : m_intCB(0)
```

should be:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : m_intCB(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

functioin pointer typedef Should be:

typedef void (*intCB)(int); //You missed the *